# Transpose constants in separate columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to find the most basic was to achieve this, but I have not been able to. I have a simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT 'Column_a','Column_ab','Column_ac','Column_ad'
```

which returns

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
----------------    ----------------    ----------------    ----------------
Column_a            Column_ab           Column_ac           Column_ad
```

What I really want is to get:

```
Column_a
Column_ab
Column_ac
Column_ad
```

I can't use Pivot since it requires an aggregate function.

Comment: Do I need to create separate SQL statements? Sucks if I have to...

Comment: Are you hard-coding these values? Otherwise could you explain where they come from? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Ya they are hard coded. I need them to be in SQL

Comment: I can't really use PIVOT since it requires an aggregate function. My problem is simple enough that it makes the solution difficult. My query is that simple. I just need to return those 4 exact values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On SQL Server 2008 and above, you can re-write this slightly:

```
SELECT x FROM (VALUES
  ('Column_a'),('Column_ab'),('Column_ac'),('Column_ad')
) AS y(x);
```

Results:

```
x
---------
Column_a
Column_ab
Column_ac
Column_ad
```

Though keep in mind there is no way to guarantee that they're ordered as written, unless you add another column to assist in ordering. In this case it happens to be that you wrote them in alphabetical order, so you could `ORDER BY x`, but that is just a lucky coincidence.

An `UNPIVOT` example with similar caveats, though an advantage of just wrapping your original query with additional code:

```
SELECT x FROM
(
  SELECT 'Column_a', 'Column_ab', 'Column_ac', 'Column_ad'
) AS p(a,b,c,d)
UNPIVOT (x FOR cols IN (a,b,c,d)) AS up;
```

(Actually, this will only work well if all the strings are the same length. Otherwise you get the following error message.)

> Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1
>   
> The type of column "b" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

To work around that, you need to wrap each constant that is NOT of the most common length with an explicit `CONVERT` to the same type and length (placing the longest string first doesn't help, as it might in some other cases). Otherwise the `VALUES` approach seems much cleaner.

Comment: Won't you have to `cast` `column_a` since it has a different data length? The one without a cast fails because the columns are different lengths and unpivot requires everything to be identical -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17610

Comment: @bluefeet yep, caught that in the meantime too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most basic way to do this would be with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Column_a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Column_ab'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Column_ac'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Column_ad'
```

Not sure if that's appropriate in your circumstances though without seeing a "real" query.